# Orders are not displaying in admin on Opencart (authorize.net & v1.5.5.1)

Tags: opencart, e-commerce, authorize.net

My team and I are trying to finalize an e-commerce build and we've run into a snag with our order processing on Opencart v1.5.5.1.

We're currently using authoize.net as our payment gateway.  The orders are being processed (reflected on both the test credit card and the authorize.net transaction gateway)

However, when the order is placed it automatically is sent to the 'missing orders' variable under orders rather than your normal 'pending' status.

We can go in and manually change over the orders, but that's not going to fly with the client.  The goal is to have these automatically display as 'pending'.  Apparently, this is a common problem with opencart and authorize.net (see http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=79388&p=347416#p347416) but their suggested solution isn't doing the trick.

Has anyone else encountered this problem for Opencart 1.5.5.1 and how did you get around it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is within the configuration of the `authorize.net` payment gateway. Did You set the order status within administration of the authorize.net payment gateway correctly?

[image: authorize.net administration]

Default status is *Canceled* (which is weird) so set it to *Pending*. After the payment was successfully processed this order status is used (see `catalog/controller/payment/authorize_aim.php` at lines 136-166).

Comment: Hey Shady, 

I wish that was the problem!  It's currently configurated for 'Pending'.  What appears to be happening is: 

The data is being sent out to authorize.net
The information is being confirmed, and data is being sent back to our opencart install, however it doesn't appear to be recognizing the proper MD5 Hash.

Comment: OK, now I did look at the link You have provided (as I didn't yesterday). I guess it would be essential to find out how is the HASH created during the request being processed by the authorize.net service and try to repair the hash creation and comparing within OpenCart...Do You have access to some authorize.net specs?

Comment: Figured out the fix!  It was a combination of switching out the authorize_aim.php script with the script referenced here: https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/3929a72a682974c78cfea2a1b38f9a606b8fa95b/upload/catalog/controller/payment/authorizenet_aim.php and applying the commenting technique in the other post.

Comment: @JeffG So now You should share Your solution and post Your own answer here that You would accept... That's what this community is about... In the future others looking for similar problem may find Your own Q + A and solve their problems, too...

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error for a while now. I re-uploaded the following files and it worked for me.

Sounds like your file needs updating in

CODE: SELECT ALL
catalog/controller/account/login.php
And I would also upload a fresh

CODE: SELECT ALL
catalog/model/account/customer.php

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a very easy fix. All you need to do is goto your settings of your OpenCart Authorize.net mod and enter a MD5 Hash. Copy that go to authorize.net account click on settings next to where you find get API transaction key there is a link to update MD5 Hash. Click on that; paste the MD5 hash you copied from opencart and save.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually add the statuses back in System/Localisation/Order Statuses.